# Apache camel in desktop

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-camel

Is it possible to use Apache camel in a desktop application?

And how can I store the result of a route (like weather) in a string so I can show it on a JLabel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is possible.

> result of a route

is in Camel Exchange at last `to` component on the route

So per Camel documentation [Pojo Consuming](http://camel.apache.org/pojo-consuming.html)

> Use the Bean endpoint:
>   You can always use the bean endpoint
>   from(uri).to("bean:myBean?method=methodName");

then if you have a bean with method which accepts appropriate Class (e.g. your `weather`) as parameter you have your route result.
Then you can do with it whatever you want to.

Or last component in route can be an implementation of Camel Processor interface (Camel `process` component) which will do the same, but extract Body from camel Exchange is up to you.